# “L'indulgere” o “Indulgere”, differenze e contesti d'uso

Tags: grammar

> - *L'indulgere* nello struggersi non produce altro che la continuazione perenne delle guerre in corso.
>
> - *Indulgere* nello struggersi non produce altro che la continuazione perenne delle guerre in corso.

Secondo voi, cari amici, le testé trascritte frasi, sono differenti o, magari, no?

E quali sono le ragioni per cui un parlante italiano dovrebbe preferire la prima alla seconda o viceversa?

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers to your question, please consider the option to "accept" an answer by clicking a checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 1):

L'uso dell'articolo determinativo è a volte usato con il fine di

a) trasformare un verbo in un sostantivo o

b) per nobilitare un'istanza di un concetto. Ad esempio, questa frase può essere pronunciata con un enfasi verbale su IL:
*Rolling Stone è IL locale [per eccellenza] di Milano!*

Nel caso specifico, siamo nel tipo a): *"l'indulgere"* sta in realtà ad indicare *"l'atto di indulgere"*.

Ai fini semantici, le due frasi nel tuo esempio sono comunque equivalenti, si tratta soltanto di una preferenza stilistica.

Comment: Non ho capito il fatto del locale di Milano. Lì la differenza sta nell'usare l'articolo determinativo anziché quello indeterminativo («Il Rolling Stone è *un* locale di Milano»), non nell'usare l'articolo anziché niente come nella domanda.

Comment: E poi, Diego, metticelo qualche accento, ogni tanto!  :-)

Comment: @DaG Era un altro esempio dell'uso di articolo determinativo con fini "inusuali", un po' OOT in effetti. Purtroppo scrivo su tastiere non italiane, non ho accenti :)

Comment: Si chiama infinito sostantivato; nonostante Treccani asserisca (implicitamente) che debba sempre essere introdotto da (parolone) un "sintagma sintattico" (articolo determinativo, articolo indeterminativo, aggettivo e altri) , altre fonti (decisamente meno accreditate) asseriscono che questo non è necessario e che, ad esempio, anche "Fumare fa male" sarebbe da considerarsi un infinito sostantivato. Non saprei.

Answer (score 0):

"L'indulgere" mi sembra cacofonico. 
Dal punto di vista logico-grammaticale non vedo motivi per preferire l'una all'altra.
Ma la vera domanda è "cos'è un utteratore?"

Comment: Un utteratore è un parlante, cioè colui che uttera parole.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider, sei conscio che, sebbene *to utter* sia una normale parola inglese, “utterare” non esiste, vero?

Comment: @DaG Cerco di coniare nuove parole per rendere più dinamica la lingua italiana. E, sì, nel caso di specie l'ispirazione era alla lingua inglese. Comunque non credo 'utterare' non esista in assoluto.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider Esiste al pari di “vorda” o “dogo” per “parola” o “cane”. Puoi parlare come credi, ma non dare la colpa all'ascoltatore se non ti capisce.

Comment: Quindi io ad una tedesca potrei rivolgermi dicendole che è una parlerin, cioè colei che parla. Il Bundestag si congratulerà con me per la dinamicità che introduco nell' Hochdeutsche Sprachen

Comment: Giusto, @AlessandroMandelli, ma devi schreibarlo con il grosso buchstabo: Parlerin.

Comment: Ganzo schono, Herro @Dag

Comment: A me "L'indulgere" non suona cacofonico, anzi. Mi sembra un pochettino più letterario/altezzoso del semplice Indulgere. 
E comunque, complimenti a tutti per la schermaglia sui neologismi...